# HIVE - How do I convert Timestamp and sum valeus

Tags: hadoop, hive, timestamp, hue, summarize

I have a timestamp value like

> 2021-09-01T00:16:18.971228-03:00

And I need to separate the hours and date. After that summarize the day values ​​and night values
My problem is how can I do this with this kind of format?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you, I created a data.frame just to show all variables together.

```
x <- "2021-09-01T00:16:18.971228-03:00"

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

tibble(x) %>% 
  mutate(
    dttm = ymd_hms(x),
    date = as_date(dttm),
    hour = hour(dttm)
  )

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  x                                dttm                date        hour
  <chr>                            <dttm>              <date>     <int>
1 2021-09-01T00:16:18.971228-03:00 2021-09-01 03:16:18 2021-09-01     3
```

Comment: I am using hadoop/hive